# WP get_footer function does not show footer and added some ids in my body

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

look at this code
this id and inline styles are not set by me! I tried to remove them in jqueryu but I couldnt.do you know any solution for this

```css
#error-page {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
body {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccd0d4;
    color: #444;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
    margin: 2em auto;
        margin-top: 2em;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    max-width: 700px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .04);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .04);
    
}
body {
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial;
}
```

```html
<body data-rsssl="1" class="rtl search search-results logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support woocommerce-no-js yith-wcbm-theme-webyarthemepro 124" id="error-page"></div>
```

Comment: From what i see this is your search page right ? And also its rtl so you should look for rtl css file. Read more here ( https://codex.wordpress.org/Right-to-Left_Language_Support ) This is not relevant to your question btw. What is your search.php template look like ?

Comment: hello.
thanks for your help. yes its search.php . 
actually you asked how is my search.php its row style like 90s of google :)))))

Comment: Like i said this is rtl style so you should look in to this file in your theme. Can you share your search.php code so we can help maybe ?